# Por qué existen los arreglos en Kotlin?

Tags: array, lista, kotlin

Buen día comunidad de StackOverflow!

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Kotlin y me ha surgido una duda respecto a sus conceptos básicos, específicamente en lo que respecta a arreglos y listas.

Las listas según lo que he investigado pueden ser tanto mutables como inmutables, sin embargo, los arreglos sólo pueden ser inmutables. Tomando en cuenta que las listas tienen un funcionamiento prácticamente idéntico a los arreglos, entonces:

**1)** Por qué existen los arreglos en Kotlin?

**2)** Por qué no usar siempre listas?

**3)** Hay casos especificos en los que un arreglo sea más conveniente que una lista?

Tengo muchas de estas preguntas porque tratando de hacer una similitud en PHP, por ejemplo, existen los arreglos y los objetos. Ambos cumplen funciones particulares y aún cuando ambos son naturalmente mutables se puede diferenciar según el nivel de complejidad del asunto que se está tratando cuándo elegir uno y cuando elegir otro.

> En Kotlin no logro definir alguna diferencia importante que me motive a usar
>   alguna vez arreglos en vez de listas.

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que puedan prestarme! Un saludo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nota: He usado la palabra array en vez de arreglo porque estoy más acostumbrado a ella

---

### ¿Por qué existen los arreglos en kotlin?

#### Compatibilidad con Java

Ten en cuenta que Kotlin está diseñado para tener el máximo grado de compatibilidad con Java, por lo que la inclusión de Arrays tiene mucho que ver con su existencia en Java.

#### Los arrays tienen una implementación clara

Un array es un tipo claro y definido: un contenedor de longitud fija de elementos del mismo tipo, al cual se accede por índice y que es mutable.

Una lista es una especificación: se define un comportamiento (una colección de elementos del mismo tipo que puede ser iterada, que puede acceder a los elementos dado un índice -no necesariamente acceso directo por índice- ...

#### Los arrays y las listas inmutables tienen un comportamiento diferente en cuanto a genéricos

Y este punto es complicado, porque en Java un array **no es genérico**. Los ingenieros de Kotlin decidieron eliminar por completo los primitivos para tener un sistema de tipos más redondo y estable, y en su esfuerzo desdibujaron aún más las diferencias entre listas y arrays.

Si miras el artículo de la doc sobre genéricos, encontrarás que se diferencia entre arrays y listas inmutables en la varianza. Es un tema un tanto complejo que alargaría  mucho esta respuesta así que tendrá que bastar que te diga en kotlin, `Array<Int>` no es un subtipo `Array<Number>`, mientras que `List<Int>` sí es un subtipo de `List<Number>`

#### Los arrays tienen tipos específicos para sus contrapartes primitivas en Java

Aparte del tipo genérico `Array<T>`, Kotlin incluye tipos específicos que se traducen literalmente a su contraparte primitiva, como `IntArray` o `DoubleArray`.

Su correspondencia, tomando un array de enteros como ejemplo, es la siguiente:

- `IntArray` - `int[]`
- `Array<Int>` - `Integer[]`

#### En resumen

Las diferencias entre arrays y listas están muy desdibujadas en kotlin, puesto que las decisiones que tomaron los ingenieros de acabar con los tipos primitivos y dividir las listas entre mutables e inmutables acercaron mucho ambos tipos. Tienen ciertas diferencias, pero son poco apreciables y las listas salen ganando casi siempre.

### ¿Por qué no usar siempre listas?

**¿Por qué no?** En Java, las listas fueron introducidas más tarde que los arrays y ofrecen una enorme mejora en cuanto a utilidad. En Effective Java, Joshua Bloch recomendaba usar listas por encima de arrays siempre que fuera posible, y así es como se ha hecho hasta ahora.

> La existencia de arrays en kotlin es probablemente un residuo de la compatibilidad, y éstos ofrecen muy pocas ventajas a cambio de poca flexibilidad.

### ¿Hay casos especificos en los que un arreglo sea más conveniente que una lista?

Hay casos, por ejemplo, si sabes que vas a trabajar con un número fijo de elementos y quieres acceder y cambiar esos elementos. Pero es un caso poco probable y la lista mutable puede cumplir perfectamente con esta función, además de permitirte cambiar de implementación más adelante si así lo prefieres.

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Me ha quedado totalmente claro. Muchas gracias!!! Con razón era un poco ilógica la aplicación de arrays en Kotlin para mi. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Un arreglo o array debe de usarse cuando sabes el tamaño fijo de antemano que vas a necesitar o lo conoces dinámicamente.

Una lista debe de usarse cuando desconoces el tamaño, o bien este va a fluctuar muy a menudo (sobre todo en las posiciones centrales que son las más costosas de modificar), o puede llegar a ser muy grande en algún momento y en otros momentos muy pequeños (ahorro de memoria frente a tener un array enorme siempre), o bien vas a borrar objetos y no quieres/necesitas mantener posiciones vacías (pues en el array no se pueden eliminar posiciones, o bien no puedes permitirte crear un nuevo array con menso posiciones y copiarle el contenido interesante).

Después ya, cada lenguaje puede tener sus propias implementaciones/interfaces y tener una serie de arreglos y listas específicas para cada propósito, como es el caso de Java con la [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

Nota: Kotlin corre sobre la JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte CGG. Lo que comentas en tu explicación de arreglo encaja de igual forma con el concepto y aplicación de listas inmutables. Precisamente porque conozco esta información es que se origina mi pregunta y mi solicitud de ejemplos prácticos en el uso de arreglos en Kotlin. Gracias nuevamente por tu aporte +1 porque ha sido útil.

Comment: La diferencia sería que en una colección inmutable, tu no puedes cambiarle los objetos, es decir, se quedaría como un simple expositorio una vez kla hayas construido. Mientras, en un array, tu tienes por ejemplo un array de 8, y tu puedes meterle hasta 8 objetos (de 0 a 8) todas las veces que quieras y modificarlos. Gracias.

Comment: Disculpame si no me he explicado bien, lo que necesito saber es algún ejemplo práctico en kotlin donde se vea por qué el uso de arreglo prevalece sobre el de lista ya que lista contempla todo lo que puede hacer un arreglo y más a mi entender. Si puedes responder a mis 3 dudas planteadas en la descripción de mi pregunta coloco tu respuesta como aceptada (+15)